# Should I apply padding and sizes to FXML or CSS?

Tags: css, javafx-8, fxml

I know that you can do what you want, but what is best practice?

Should I use CSS only to make the visual design of my application (colors, hover-effects, backgrounds, text-styles, ...)? Or should I also handle padding for the elements for it?

If you ask me, padding should be set in FXML, because you will then be able to use any CSS stylesheet and apply it to your application to give it a completely new appearance. If you handle padding in CSS and want to use that CSS for another application, it may get very ugly, right?

Some articles claim that you should do as much as you can in CSS. Is this true?

Comment: Ah, my rule of thumb for JavaFX is that layout is managed by FXML and style by CSS. Padding and size is a bit ambiguous, but probably falls under layout. Note that you can apply multiple style sheets, so if you want to you could define padding and size in one CSS file and colors, fonts etc in another. That would solve your reusability problem. This question is really a bit opinion-based though.

Comment: @James_D Why opinion based? I ask specifically for "Best practice". Or is there something wrong with that?

Comment: There's no objective measure of "best" for this, and no documented or officially recommended choice.